# Formatted printing with comprehensions

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to print the list of lists using comprehension and print format.

```
all_students = [
    ["Joe", "John", "Mary"],
    ["Tina", "Tony", "Jeff", "Béla"],
    ["Pete", "Dave"],
]

print("\n".join("group {0}, size of group: {1}, students: {2}"
                .format(idx+1, len(element), *element) for idx, element in enumerate(all_students))
)
```

Output:

```
group 1, size of group: 3, students: Joe
group 2, size of group: 4, students: Tina
group 3, size of group: 2, students: Pete
```

Expected result:

```
group 1, size of group: 3, students: Joe, John, Mary
group 2, size of group: 4, students: Tina, Tony, Jeff, Béla
group 3, size of group: 2, students: Pete, Dave
```

What I have done wrong in my code? Couldn't resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
.format(idx+1, len(element), *element)
```

with

```
.format(idx+1, len(element), ", ".join(element))
```

Comment: Why? Why that doesn't work, but why the second solution works?

Comment: It's because it's inside the `format(.....)`.  Otherwise, the `*element` unpacking should work as expected.